# asp .net mvc ajax submit is not overriding form post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to submit a form using ajax but the form keeps getting posted twice. Once with the FormCollection and the inputs and once without the inputs. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is my form, controller method and the JavaScript. I want to submit the form via ajax so that I can handle the UI using JavaScript and I want to use the FormCollection if possible or some collection like it. Please help!

**JavaScript**

```
$('#frmAddEdit').submit(function (e) {
    $('#alertFail').hide();

    var view = getUrlVars()["view"];
    var formData = $("#frmAddEdit").serialize();
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', $("#frmAddEdit")).val();
    var formURL = $(this).attr('action');

    var isSubmitted = false;

    // ajax call to save data
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { view: view, data: formData },
        success: function (response, status) {
            isSubmitted = response.data;
            if (isSubmitted == "true") {
                // switch the panels
                $('#pnlDetail').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
                $("#pnlGrid").delay(2000).animate({ width: 'toggle' });
                $('#alertSuccess').show();
                tblAdminGrid.ajax.reload();
            } else {
                $('#alertFail').show();
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#alertFail').show(); //something went HORRIBLY wrong!
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="/Admin/Edit?view=@Request.QueryString["view"].ToString()"        id="frmAddEdit" class="panel form-horizontal">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title capitalize">@ViewBag.Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="hidden" id="hdnId" name="hdnId" value="0"/>

        @if (Request.Params["view"] != null || ViewBag.View != null)
        {
            string currentView = Request.Params["view"] == null ? ViewBag.View.ToString() : Request.Params["view"].ToString();

            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_" + currentView + ".cshtml");
        }
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center-lg">
        <button class="btn btn-default cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Edit(string view, FormCollection data)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        data = isSuccessful
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing a double submit.

You've got a jquery selector firing on your #frmAddEdit, but there's a button type="submit" on that form. So when you press that button, it will fire your jquery, and also submit your form using the input button.  You should have one, or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

I think the framework is getting GET / PUT requests mixed up. Try adding an attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(string view, FormCollection data)
{
    return Json(new { data = isSuccessful });
}
```